# Странное расширение CSS и JS файлов на html странице

Tags: html, css, javascript

В исходном коде  одного сайта увидел странные расширения в названии CSS и  JS файлов вида: "*.css?1364880977"  или "*.js?1364880977" (цифры взяты примерные). Также в ссылках на изображения по всей странице. Для чего это сделано?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего это сделано для того, чтобы сбросить закэшированные изображения/css/js.

Например был у вас файл example.org/css/style.css
Он закешировался браузерами пользователей при первом заходе на сайт.
После того, как вы сделали изменения в этом файле вы, вероятно, захотите, чтобы браузеры пользователей обновили этот файл. Ctrl+F5 нажимать каждого не заставищь. А вот простановка любого гет-параметра изменит адрес файла и браузер его перекеширует. 
К примеру такой гет-параметр ?201310021 - сегодняшняя дата с единичкой на конце, мол первая версия от второго октября 2013-го.

Comment: угу, в примере похоже на unixtime :)

Answer (score 1):

чтобы не кешировалось в браузере или кешировалась текущая версия, чтобы когда файл поменялся он точно обновился у пользователя